# Remove default action?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, default-applications, dropbox

When I try and add a picture to an SMS it only lets me choose a picture from my dropbox. I accidentally hit to make it use dropbox all the time - how can I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings->Applications->Dropbox->Clear Defaults.

You can then choose an app to pick a picture again.