# Clear app default actions in Android 10

Tags: xiaomi, android-10, default-applications, android-one, mi

Mi App has silently taken over everything related to documents in my Gmail and printing in general in my phone. Whenever I do any action that is "an inch close to printing) then Mi App appears.

[image]

I cannot change it [in the usual way](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/47300/20449) because my Motorola Moto One / Android 10 (One) claims that Mi App has no defaults defined and so there is nothing to clear:

[image]

This is super-duper annoying because right now I am even not able to preview a .docx or .pdf attachment sent alongside some email, because each such tap instead of showing document preview, opens up Mi App claiming that there is no printer added.

How it is possible that some app is making some "silent" takeover of some action, without clearly showing this fact in Android's or app's configuration? Even more important -- how to get rid of this and bring the default action (of documents previews) to my Gmail?

**EDIT**: *Since this is Android on board Motorola device, it should be very close to stack Android without any significant changes from Motorola side.*

Comment: AFAIR, I never seem to succeed using the per-app "Clear defaults". I have to use ["Reset app preferences"](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140324/44325) instead.